# How i get a name without the last 4 charecter using C# substring?

Tags: c#

Using this below code i get the name only first 4 character.But i need the name except the last 4 character.

```
string fileName = Textbox1.text;
string newName = fileName.Substring(0, 4);
```

//ex: input abcdef.txt
//output:abcd

But i need output: abcdef

pls help!

thanks
Riad

Comment: Riad, you may not know this, but you can mark the best answer for your scenario as 'Answered' by clicking the Tick left to the number of votes.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I suppose what you really need is a file name without extension. For that, there's a separate method called, naturally, [`GetFileNameWithoutExtension`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfilenamewithoutextension.aspx).

Comment: That also fixes the problem that some extensions are longer than 3 characters, for instance: `index.html`

Answer (score 8):

I think that what you are *really* looking for is [`Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfilenamewithoutextension.aspx).

```
// prints abcdef
Console.WriteLine(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension("abcdef.txt"));
```

Answer (score 4):

```
string newName = fileName.Substring(0, fileName.Length - 4);
```

Of course, that only works if your extension is 3 characters long (and there is an extension).

Answer (score 2):

```
string newName = fileName.Substring(0, fileName.Length-4);
```

Answer (score 2):

In addition to what's already been said, and for anyone interested, there is nothing magical about the `System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension` method. It simply looks for the last `.` in the full filename using `LastIndexOf()`.

So all it does under the hood is:

```
public static string GetFileNameWithoutExtension(string path)
{
    path = GetFileName(path);
    if (path == null)
    {
        return null;
    }
    int length = path.LastIndexOf('.');
    if (length == -1)
    {
        return path;
    }
    return path.Substring(0, length);
}
```